# sharing login with between subdomains in sails

Tags: sails.js, single-sign-on

I have two applications in two separated sub-domains like: app1.example.com and app2.example.com, the database is shared between each other, the sessions store in database, the question is 
if the user login to first app then he switch  to the second app how can I keep him logged in? 
I am using sails.js and redis to store sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works after adding domain in cookies for both applications,
Change in file config/session.js

```
cookie : {
   domain: ".example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was making sure that we have same secret key for all the web apps. Secret key can be configured in config -> session.js.

Answer (score -1):

It will be almost like scaling
Preparing your app for a clustered deployment

> The most important thing to remember about scaling a server-side
>   application is that it should be stateless. That means you should be
>   able to deploy the same code to n different servers, expecting any
>   given incoming request handled by any given server, and everything
>   should still work. Luckily, Sails apps come ready for this kind of
>   deployment almost right out of the box. But before deploying your app
>   to multiple servers, there are a few things you need to do:
>
> Ensure none of the other dependencies you might be using in your app
>   rely on shared memory. Make sure the database(s) for your models (e.g.
>   MySQL, Postgres, Mongo) are scalable (e.g. sharding/cluster) If your
>   app uses sessions: Configure your app to use a shared session store
>   such as Redis (simply uncomment the adapter option in
>   config/session.js) and install the connect-redis adapter as a
>   dependency of your app (e.g. npm install connect-redis@~3.0.2 --save
>   --save-exact). If your app uses sockets: Configure your app to use Redis as a shared message queue for delivering socket.io messages
>   (uncomment the adapter option in config/sockets.js) Install the
>   socket.io-redis adapter as a dependency of your app (e.g. npm install
>   socket.io-redis@~1.0.0 --save --save-exact) If your cluster is on a
>   single server (for instance, using pm2 cluster mode) To avoid file
>   conflict issues due to Grunt tasks, always start your apps in
>   production environment, and/or consider turning Grunt off completely.
>   See here for more details on Grunt issues in single-server clusters Be
>   careful with config/bootstrap.js code that persists data in a
>   database, to avoid conflicts when the bootstrap runs multiple times
>   (once per node in the cluster)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am not asking about scaling, I just want to know how can I apply single sign on multiple applications which have the same database and session is stored  on redis which is also shared among them

Comment: I told you - you have to do THE SAME as for scalling. Two different applications using the same database is almost the same as scalling the same app. Difference is that you have to enable session store in REDIS on both and it will work

Comment: I already enabled it , It is working now after setting parent domain in cookies in both